# Jtable editabe with JtextField and FocusTraversalPolicy

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, jtextfield

By running the example (neglected but functional to demonstrate my problem) you can see the steps in the console in the focustraversalpolicy

Test1: simply press TAB or ShiftTab
In console you see the steps in the getComponentAfter and getComponentBefore methods; in particular it is seen that, since the cells are not in edit, in the case of the second component, the JScrollPane component is returned. so it's ok

Test2: click on a JTable cell, write something (to enter edit) and press TAB
In console you see the passage in the getComponentAfter method; in particular it is seen that, having the focus the JTable, the JTable component is returned. so it's ok

Test3: click on a JTable cell, write something (to enter edit) and press ShiftTAB
Nothing happens at least in terms of focustraversalpolicy
If you press ShiftTab again
In console you see the passage in the getComponentBefore method; in particular we see that the JTextField component used for editing the cell is returned

Why shift TAB first time have no effect on on focustraversalpolicy policy?

Why TAB in focustraversalpolicy return a JTable component and Shift TAB return a JTextField component?

```
public class Prova2
{
    public static final Double VideoDefaultFontIncrementWidth = 0.92;
    public static final Double VideoDefaultFontIncrementHeight = 1.5;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Prova2();
            }
        });
    }

    public Prova2()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prova");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //
        Object[] columnHeaders = {"Codice", "Nome", "Prezzo", "Data", "Noedit"};
        Object rows[][] = { 
            { "A", "About", 44.36, null, "aa" }, 
            { "B", "Boy", 44.84, null, "aa" }, 
            { "C", "Cat", 463.63, null, "aa" }, 
            { "D", "Day", 27.14, null, "aa" }, 
            { "E", "Eat", 44.57, null, "aa" }, 
            { "F", "Fail", 23.15, null, "aa" }, 
            { "G", "Good", 4.40, null, "aa" }, 
            { "H", "Hot", 24.96, null, "aa" }, 
            { "I", "Ivey", 5.45, null, "aa" }, 
            { "J", "Jack", 49.54, null, "aa" }, 
            { "K", "Kids", 280.00, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2A", "About", 44.36, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2B", "Boy", 44.84, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2C", "Cat", 463.63, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2D", "Day", 27.14, null, "aa"}, 
            { "2E", "Eat", 44.57, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2F", "Fail", 23.15, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2G", "Good", 4.40, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2H", "Hot", 24.96, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2I", "Ivey", 5.45, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2J", "Jack", 49.54, null, "aa" }, 
            { "2K", "Kids", 280.00, null, "aa" } };
        //
        // text 1
        JTextField Text1 = new JTextField("");
        Text1.setName("Text1");
        frame.add(Text1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //
        // JTable soluzione 2
        JTable myTable = new JTable(rows, columnHeaders);
        myTable.setName("Table");
        myTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        myTable.putClientProperty("autoStartsEdit", true);
        myTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);
        ActionMap myTableActionMap = myTable.getActionMap();
        myTableActionMap.put("selectPreviousColumnCell", new myPreviousFocusHandler());
        myTableActionMap.put("selectNextColumnCell", new myNextFocusHandler());
        for (int i = 0; i < myTable.getColumnCount()-1; i++)
        {
            JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
            myTable.getColumn(columnHeaders[i]).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(myTextField));
        }
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(myTable);
        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);       
        //
        // text2
        JTextField Text2 = new JTextField("");
        Text2.setName("Text2");
        frame.add(Text2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //
        // frame
        frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new MyFocusTraversalPolicy());
        frame.setSize(800, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class MyFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy
    {
        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container arg0, Component arg1)
        {
            System.out.println("getComponentAfter1: "+arg1.toString());
            JRootPane myRootPane=(JRootPane)arg0.getComponent(0);
            JPanel myPanel = (JPanel) myRootPane.getLayeredPane().getComponent(0);
            if (arg1 instanceof JPanel == true)
            {
                return getFirstComponent(arg0);
            }
            int myNewPosition = 0;
            myNewPosition = myComponentPosition(myPanel, arg1);
            myNewPosition = myComponentNext(myPanel, myNewPosition, 1);
            if (myNewPosition > -1)
            {
                System.out.println("getComponentAfter2: "+myComponent(myPanel, myNewPosition));
                return myComponent(myPanel, myNewPosition);
            }
            else
            {
                return getFirstComponent(arg0);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(Container arg0, Component arg1)
        {
            System.out.println("getComponentBefore1: "+arg1.toString());
            JRootPane myRootPane=(JRootPane)arg0.getComponent(0);
            JPanel myPanel = (JPanel) myRootPane.getLayeredPane().getComponent(0);
            if (arg1 instanceof JPanel == true)
            {
                return getFirstComponent(arg0);
            }
            int myNewPosition = 0;
            myNewPosition = myComponentPosition(myPanel, arg1);
            myNewPosition = myComponentNext(myPanel, myNewPosition, -1);
            if (myNewPosition > -1)
            {
                System.out.println("getComponentBefore2: "+myComponent(myPanel, myNewPosition));
                return myComponent(myPanel, myNewPosition);
            }
            else
            {
                return getLastComponent(arg0);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container arg0)
        {
            System.out.println("getDefaultComponent1: ");
            JRootPane myRootPane=(JRootPane)arg0.getComponent(0);
            JPanel myPanel = (JPanel) myRootPane.getLayeredPane().getComponent(0);
            System.out.println("getDefaultComponent2: "+myPanel.getComponent(0));
            return myPanel.getComponent(0);
        }
        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(Container arg0)
        {
            System.out.println("getFirstComponent1: ");
            JRootPane myRootPane=(JRootPane)arg0.getComponent(0);
            JPanel myPanel = (JPanel) myRootPane.getLayeredPane().getComponent(0);
            System.out.println("getFirstComponent2: "+myPanel.getComponent(0));
            return myPanel.getComponent(0);
        }
        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(Container arg0)
        {
            System.out.println("getLastComponent1: ");
            JRootPane myRootPane=(JRootPane)arg0.getComponent(0);
            JPanel myPanel = (JPanel) myRootPane.getLayeredPane().getComponent(0);
            System.out.println("getLastComponent2: "+myPanel.getComponent(myPanel.getComponentCount()-1));
            return myPanel.getComponent(myPanel.getComponentCount()-1);
        }
        private int myComponentPosition(Container parm_Container, Component parm_Component)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parm_Container.getComponentCount(); i++)
            {
                if (parm_Container.getComponent(i) == parm_Component)
                {
                    return i;
                }
                if (parm_Container.getComponent(i).getClass() == JScrollPane.class)
                {
                    if (parm_Component.getClass() == JTable.class)
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        private int myComponentNext(Container parm_Container, int parm_Position, int parm_Increment)
        {
            for (int i = parm_Position + parm_Increment; i > -1 && i < parm_Container.getComponentCount(); i = i + parm_Increment)
            {
                if (parm_Container.getComponent(i).isEnabled() && parm_Container.getComponent(i).isFocusable())
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private Component myComponent(Container parm_Container, int parm_Position)
        {
            return parm_Container.getComponent(parm_Position);
        }
    }


    public class myPreviousFocusHandler extends AbstractAction
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            KeyboardFocusManager myManager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
            myManager.focusPreviousComponent();
        }
    }

    public class myNextFocusHandler extends AbstractAction
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            KeyboardFocusManager myManager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
            myManager.focusNextComponent();
        }

    }

}
```